# The definition of subbasis in Topology

Tags: general-topology

I have a question regarding the subbasis; in Munkre's topology, the subbasis is defined in the following picture. But if I take a collection that only contains the set X, can it be a subbasis for a topology on X?

[image: Difinition of Subbasis in Topology]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your thought about your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a collection that contains only the set $X$, then clearly union of all the members of that collection will be $X$. So, definitely that collection will be a subbasis and the topology generated by this subbasis is the indiscrete topology which contains only two sets $X$ and the null set $\phi$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can normally take any set of subsets (subset of $\mathscr P(X),$ the power set) and consider the topology it generates. That's the smallest (coarsest) topology that contains it.

But Munkres has chosen to say that to be a subbasis it must have union equal to $X.$